# definition of expected value using measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, probability

When I am reading the Wiki, the general definition of expected value of random variable $X$ on probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ is defined as
$$\int_{\Omega}X(w)dP(w)$$
For me, I know that $P(w)$ is the probability measure of $w$. However, I can not understand the term $dP(w)$ in the equation above. It is a little abstract for me, and how can we explain this term?

Comment: It is just another notation for $\int_{\Omega} XdP$ the integral of $X$ w.r.t. the measure $P$.

Answer (score 2):

$dP(w)$ means integration wrt the measure $P$. As the name implies, probability measures are measures, so we can integrate over them. That is, $P$ is a measure on $\Omega$ (it is not the distribution of $X$! It is the distribution over the whole outcome space). Since random variables are measurable functions $X: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, we can integrate them wrt the measure $P$.

If this does not make much sense to you, look a bit more into Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

$dP(w)=p(w)dw$

as per definition

$\frac{d}{dw}P=p$

Comment: Thanks. What is the explicit meaning of function p(w)? I know it is the derivative of P(w).