# Explain how to translate Lebesgue to Riemann integral in expected value definition

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral, expected-value, riemann-integration

I have such general equation for expected value definition in [this book](https://vk.com/doc126754362_437580661?hash=bdcb3ed758f1aed191&dl=16803cd5bd1204baab), p 64
$$
E(X)=\int_\Omega \omega(\zeta)P(d\zeta)
$$
where $\omega$ is random value and $P$ is probability function.

How to translate it to classic Riemann integral definition

$$
E(X)= \int_\Omega w(\zeta)f(\zeta)d\zeta
$$

where $f(\zeta)$ is probability density? I found [simular question there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745816/definition-of-expected-value-using-measure-theory), but there is another designation

Comment: It's very nearly the same thing, with the second equation being equivalent to the first if $P$ has probability density $f$. The one minor catch is that technically the integral in the first equation is Lebesgue and in the second it is Riemann, but you just need the theorem that if a function is Riemann integrable then it is Lebesgue integrable and its Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are equal.

Comment: Ok, got it, but how to understand $P(d\zeta)$ notation? Is it defining like that:
$\int F(dx) = \int f(x) dx $ where $F'(x) = f(x)$?

Comment: $P(d\zeta)$ is one of the commonly used notations for Lebesgue integration in the variable $\zeta$ against the measure $P$. Don't read too much into the notation for some kind of "deeper meaning" because it's really not there.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's the thing I want to understand!

Comment: Just need it to compute conditional expectation value $E(X|B) = \int \omega(\zeta) P_{B}(d\zeta)$